# Formatting data as money in a RadWatermarkTextbox

Tags: wpf, vb.net, telerik

I want the user to enter data for freight rate as an American monetary amount such as $23.45.  They would enter 23.45

If set up as a RadWatermarkTextbox, 23.45 cannot be entered without going thru these steps:

```
 1) Enter 23   
 2) Use the arrow key to navigate to the cents (skip over the decimal point)   
 3) Enter 45 (.00 shifts over to the right making it look like $23.45.00)   
 4) Delete the .00
```

I changed the format to StringFormat='#.00', StringFormat=F2, and no string format.  These did not solve the problem.

I found this suggestion online but am not able to enter the decimal point.  All that can be entered is 2345.

```
    Private Sub txtDefaultFreightRate_PreviewTextInput(sender As Object, e As TextCompositionEventArgs) Handles txtDefaultFreightRate.PreviewTextInput

    Dim regex As New Regex("^[.][0-9]+$|^[0-9]*[.]{0,1}[0-9]*$")
    e.Handled = Not regex.IsMatch(TryCast(sender, System.Windows.Controls.TextBox).Text.Insert(TryCast(sender, System.Windows.Controls.TextBox).SelectionStart, e.Text))

    For Each ch As Char In e.Text
        If Not ([Char].IsDigit(ch) OrElse ch.Equals("."c)) Then
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

XAML for FreightRate:

```
<telerik:RadWatermarkTextBox x:Name="txtDefaultFreightRate"
    Margin="0,2,0,0"
    Text="{Binding defaultFreightRate, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, StringFormat='{}{0:C2}'}" 
    <telerik:RadWatermarkTextBox.WatermarkContent>
        <TextBlock Text="Enter in format $$$.$$ " FontSize="12" Foreground="#969696" />
    </telerik:RadWatermarkTextBox.WatermarkContent>
</telerik:RadWatermarkTextBox>
```

If changed to a wpf TextBox, then entering data as money works as expected.  XAML for this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding defaultFreightRate, Mode=TwoWay, StringFormat='{}{0:C2}'}" Width="100" Height="25" />
```

Is it not possible to format data entry as money in a RadWatermarkTextBox?  I'm not finding much online about this.  I assumed formatting would be the same as a regular textbox.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`:

```
<telerik:RadWatermarkTextBox x:Name="txtDefaultFreightRate"
                             Margin="0,2,0,0"
                             Text="{Binding defaultFreightRate, Mode=TwoWay, StringFormat='{}{0:C2}'}">
    <telerik:RadWatermarkTextBox.WatermarkContent>
        <TextBlock Text="Enter in format $$$.$$ " FontSize="12" Foreground="#969696" />
    </telerik:RadWatermarkTextBox.WatermarkContent>
</telerik:RadWatermarkTextBox>
```

Comment: Thanks.  That fixed the issue.